# What is a good reason to tell clients who want their logo to be always included in every screen that it shouldn't be done for a mobile app?

Tags: layout, mobile-application, usability-testing, branding, client

Just as the title says, I'm not a fan of **always displaying the logo at the title bar of a specific app**. I sometimes come across a client whose concept screens are like that.  What would be a good reason to tell them why it shouldn't be done? They usually want their branding to be emphasized all through out the app and I'm not confident as to what I can tell them to avoid it.

Reasons that I can think of are:

1. It would consume screen space.
2. Branding can be expressed in other ways like button color, etc.
3. It would annoy the user ( as the trend is logo can only be seen at the start )
4. It is a website thing.

Though with these reasons, I'm kinda anxious that the client would tell me:

1. Color and layout is not enough
2. I want my logo to be remembered
3. The logo would be an indication that they are using the app.

Any insights would be nice regarding this problem, as I am not sure myself what would be the best solution for it. Thanks in advance!

edit:

I also noticed that it is a trend of consumer apps to only put the logo in the title bar when they are at the start of the app, anyone know what the reasoning behind this is?

Comment: Do you have data why you should not display the logo? If you have research that proofs for instance that the space you get from not showing the logo reduces bounce by 10% then you can start a discussion. If it is not backed up by data you are both just guessing.

Comment: The only data I have is that most of consumer apps nowadays do not include their logo to every single page there is.

Comment: A common pattern I see is using the logo as a "home" button. Why not just do that? Then it has a purpose. If it consumes space, it should do so for a reason.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the client says the logo must appear on all the company screens, even those of the mobile application is absolutely correct and of course, they are in their right to say that.

---

But, this is where the professionalism of a graphic designer comes from: for this situation, there are *design variables* in a corporate image. Nowadays a logo is not simply the image of the company as such to be implemented as a single element in a corner of the screen or printed paper, but also all its possible applications. In fact, many brands incorporate what could be called the "responsive" version of the logo. The company image today should have also its adaptability to different media such as the icon of a social network, the button of a possible future application, or simply a different layout to the one established as the basis. An extreme example is a *favicon*.

Here are some examples:

[image]

*Image from [diony.co.uk](https://diony.co.uk/web-design-hull/responsive-logos-way-forward/)*

Conclusion: If the client insists the logo must appear on all their application screens, propose or request the company image have all the necessary visual versions to make this feasible while maintaining maximum visual quality. If the client doesn't know about the image versions of the company (most likely), simply explain what this is.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback! But usually the titlebar in an application contains the "title" of the screen as to give context to the current screen. Should this be compromised to still include the logo?

Comment: My answer is how a designer should act on a request made by a client with a possible answer and a professional solution. How this should be implemented in design responds to each particular case. Particularly I don't see any problem in placing the app logo version with the title. Perhaps the question is not whether or not the logo should be placed but how the screen title design should be.

Comment: If you absolutely cannot eliminate the logo, at the very least make sure it's not occupying the most valuable real-estate on the screen, which for western users is the top left.  You could try showing them mockups with the logo in various places, and explain to them the limitations of each.  Given the limited screen size of a phone,  demanding a logo on each page of a UI will restrict its functionality, and the customer should understand the tradeoff.  Your job is not to tell them they can't have a logo, but show them the tradeoffs.  If they still want one after that, smile and do it.

Comment: Thank you, I guess it all truly depends on the client. @DanHanson It is kinda challenging to design an app which has a logo always at the top, and I am also careful as I may be not following proper mobile design guidelines.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid that there will be always be stakeholders who overrule you. If they say it's a must, there's not much you can do about it.

That being said, your number one reason (it would consume screen space) is a fair one. Especially on mobile devices, the limited screen space needs to be considered. Try to back your arguments with examples of other apps or websites.

The [Nielsen Norman Group](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/mobile-ux/) also mentions the limitations of smaller screen sizes:

> [...] screen size is a serious limitation for mobile devices. The content displayed above the fold on a 30 inch monitor requires 5 screenfuls on a small 4-inch screen. [...]

Maybe numbers are more convincing to your stakeholders? Try calculating how many percent of a frequently used phone [screen size](http://screensiz.es/phone) is lost to the logo and how many additional screens are necessary to display the same amount of your content based on that assumption.

Comment: Using numbers is a very good suggestions, though I am the only person in my department so I have no resources on getting these things. I can do some research but that is about it.